# Configurar o padding dos cabeçalhos do meu DataTable (Bootstrap) através do JavaScript e CSS

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-datatables

Preciso configurar o padding dos cabeçalhos do meu DataTable (Bootstrap) através do JavaScript e CSS, pois as setas estão ficando muito próximas aos títulos do cabeçalho e ficando desordenadas quando as colunas são dimensionadas. Eu tentei usar JS, mas não consegui...
 Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
.align-right {
    text-align: right;
    /*max-width: 80px*/
}

.align-left {
    text-align: left;
    /*max-width: 80px*/
}

.align-center {
    text-align: center;
    /*max-width: 80px*/
}

table.center-header th {
    text-align: center;
}

table.dataTable thead span.sort-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 23px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

```js
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered dataTable table-striped width-full center-header table-responsive" id="bancoGridDataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PessoaViewModel.PessoaNatureza)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PessoaViewModel.PessoaJuridicaViewModel.RazaoSocial)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PessoaViewModel.PessoaJuridicaViewModel.NomeFantasia)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CodigoBanco)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayName("Ações")
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PessoaViewModel.PessoaNaturezaDescricao)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PessoaViewModel.PessoaJuridicaViewModel.RazaoSocial)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PessoaViewModel.PessoaJuridicaViewModel.NomeFantasia)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CodigoBanco)
                    </td>

                    <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" title="Editar" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default edit-row">
                            <span class="icon-2x wb-edit"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id" title="Detalhes" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default footable-row-detail-row">
                            <span class="icon-2x wb-search"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" title="Excluir" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default remove-row">
                            <span class="icon-2x wb-trash"></span>
                        </a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default remove-row" title="Histórico" data-id="@item.Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customerHistory" data-original-title="Histórico">
                            <span class="icon-2x wb-time"></span>
                        </button>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#bancoGridDataTable').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [
                { className: "align-right", "targets": [4] },
                { className: "align-center", "targets": [5] },
                { className: "align-right", "targets": [0] },
                { className: "table.dataTable thead span.sort-icon", "targets": [0] }
            ],
            language: {
                "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ".",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                "searchPlaceholder": "Pesquise qualquer coisa",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sNext": "Próximo",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                    "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                    "sLast": "Último"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                }
            }            
        });
```

Comment: Cara acho que seria mais interessante colocar o CSS nas setas e não no texto. Tipo nas setinhas coloque um "margin-left" e olha se funciona. Vc usou algum framework com essas tabelas com setas ou vc fez na mão, tem como acessar essa tabela por algum link?

Comment: Eu usei um framework... Eu acrescentei um margin-left no bloco css "table.dataTable thead span.sort-icon {" mas não funcionou... Como chamo a classe na tag <th>??

Comment: Cara clique com o botão direito do mous na setinha e mante "Inspecionar" ai vc olha a classe css que elas têm e coloca o margin-left nela. Se no lugar que vc pegou o framework tiver um modelo dessa tabela me passa o link que dou uma olhada pra vc.

Comment: Ele está apontando para o arquivo bootstrap-extend.min... Eu tentei mudar o margin-left e o padding dela mas não funcionou... se quiser, posso te mandar o arquivo css por e-mail.. ele é grande para ser pstado aqui...